# How to implement C2DM in android

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am try implement C2DM in Android. I am able to get Registration code after registration with C2DM Server. But when I send message from 3rd party server, it displays message "message sent" and error  code 200  in Log, which means 3rd party server have successfully send the message. BuT my problem is that, I am not able to receive message in device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog http://www.tomasmalmsten.com/tag/c2dm/ is excellent for getting android c2dm up and running.

Answer (score 0):

```
function googleAuthenticate($username, $password, $source="Company-AppName-Version", $service="ac2dm"){  

       $ch = curl_init();
       if(!$ch){
           return false;
       }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
        $post_fields = "accountType=" . urlencode('HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE')
        . "&Email=" . urlencode($username)
        . "&Passwd=" . urlencode($password)
        . "&source=" . urlencode($source)
        . "&service=" . urlencode($service);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (strpos($response, '200 OK') === false) {
        return false;
        }
        // find the auth code
        preg_match("/(Auth=)([\w|-]+)/", $response, $matches);

        if (!$matches[2]) {
        return false;
        }
        return $matches[2];
   }

   // send message to android,  The message size limit is 1024 bytes in android

  function c2dmSendMessageToPhone($authCode, $deviceRegistrationId, $msgType, $messageText,$extraArr) {
            $headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authCode);
            $data1 = array(
                    'registration_id' => $deviceRegistrationId,
                    'collapse_key' => $msgType,
                    'data.msg' => $messageText         
                    );
            $data2 = array();
            // append 'data' string in key of the array
            if(!empty($extraArr)){
                    foreach($extraArr as $k => $v){
                        $data2['data.'.$k] = $v;
                        unset($extraArr[$k]);
                    }
            }

            $data = array_merge($data1,$data2);
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
            if ($headers)
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $response; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check this post [C2DM Implementation Checklist Step by Step](http://situee.blogspot.com/2011/08/c2dm-implementation-checklist-step-by.html)

Including 1 Things before coding; 2 Android App(client side); 3 Server side: [get ClientLogin](http://situee.blogspot.com/2011/08/c2dm-get-clientlogin-authentication.html) etc; 4 Notes

Answer (score 0):

Everyone tuning in into this topic should be aware of a change at Google:

C2DM is deprecated and has been replaced by [Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM)](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).
Google's statement:

```
Important: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012.
This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota requests. 
No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using C2DM will continue to work. 
Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to migrate to the new version of C2DM, 
called Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM).
See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more information.
Developers must use GCM for new development.
```

There is a [demo app tutorial for GCM](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html) and also for [migration](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html) from C2DM.